# Converting 2-dimensional array into 1-D array( with conditions)

Tags: c

I have a two-dimensional(3x7) array and i would like to convert into a 1-D array such that the row that I provide is in the centre. The row value could vary along the way, but it has to be in the centre.

```
#define numRows 3
#define numCols 7
#define TotalNum 21

int arr[numRows-1][numCols-1] =
                    { {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10,11,12,13}, {14,15,16,17,18,19,20} };
int stack[TotalNum-1];

stackup(arr,stack,row);

void stackup(int *p,int *s,int &row1)
{     
    int k =0;  
    for(int i = 0; i<numRows; i++) 
    {         
        for(int j = 0; j<numCols; j++)
        {           
            s[k] = p[i][j];
            k++;
        }              
    } 
}
```

The function stackup is definitely wrong and needs to be tweaked, but I'm not sure how to tweak it such that the row provided is in the centre when pushed into stack.

Comment: Well, you have to get rid of the -1's in your array declarations for one thing.

Comment: Because `int arr[15];` declares an array of 15 `int`s, not one where the last admissible index is 15.

Comment: so an arr[3][7] intitalises a 3x 7 matrix... but arr[2][6] only has 12 terms inside... and arr[3][7] has arr[0][], arr[1][] and arr[2][]. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define numRows 3
#define numCols 7
#define TotalNum (numRows*numCols)

void stackup(int **p,int *s,int row1)
{     
    int k = 0,t;
    int middle = (numRows-1)/2;
    for (int i = 0; i<numRows; i++) {
        t=i;
        if (i==middle || i==row1)
            i = (i==row1)?middle:row1;
        for (int j = 0; j<numCols; j++)
            s[k++] = p[i][j];
        i=t;
    }
}
```

Basically adds sequentially all the elements from 'p' row by row into 's'. When it's time for the middle row, the elements from row1 are added instead. When it's time for the elements of row1 to be added the elements from the middle row are added instead.